# Small tiny white / amber mites running around the sides of the pot

Tags: pests, bugs, organic

I have found in my pots some kind of tiny white bug, kind of mite I think. They are very very small, like a grain of dust, and they do not seem to be on under the leaves or on the stalks. They do not jump, nor do I see webbings and they have been 2 weeks here.
They are running around the sides and on top of the pot, and they seem to come from the sides of the soil. Ant-like speed. I even found them outside of the pots in the table where the plant is, and beause it's inside a bedroom, I would like to get rid of them, even if they are beneficial, because they are growing in numbers a lot. I have some pyrethrin with colza seed oil which I can use, but was trying to avoid it. Does somebody knows what they are and how to get rid of them? I can't transplant unfortunately.. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a picture please

Comment: Hi kevinskio, I could, but you won't see anything. They can't be seen on camera, they are too small, the size of a grain of dust. And I can't provide pictures with magnification unfortunately :(